# scala flink java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl

Tags: scala, apache-flink

When I package the flink program, and I run the jar with the command `scala -classpath my-flink-2-11-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar com.littlely.batch.SimpleWordCount`, but it went some error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.<init>(Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/typesafe/config/Config;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Lscala/Option;Lscala/Option;Lakka/actor/setup/ActorSystemSetup;)V
        at akka.actor.RobustActorSystem.<init>(RobustActorSystem.scala:41)
        at akka.actor.RobustActorSystem$.internalApply(RobustActorSystem.scala:89)
        at akka.actor.RobustActorSystem$.apply(RobustActorSystem.scala:70)
        at akka.actor.RobustActorSystem$.create(RobustActorSystem.scala:55)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:125)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:113)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.AkkaUtils.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster.createRpcService(MiniCluster.java:743)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.MiniCluster.start(MiniCluster.java:270)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.executors.LocalExecutor.startMiniCluster(LocalExecutor.java:117)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.executors.LocalExecutor.execute(LocalExecutor.java:63)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.executeAsync(ExecutionEnvironment.java:944)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:860)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:844)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:413)
        at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.print(DataSet.java:1652)
        at org.apache.flink.api.scala.DataSet.print(DataSet.scala:1864)
        at com.littlely.batch.SimpleWordCount$.main(SimpleWordCount.scala:20)
        at com.littlely.batch.SimpleWordCount.main(SimpleWordCount.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:31)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.asContext(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$class.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:70)
        at scala.reflect.internal.util.ScalaClassLoader$URLClassLoader.run(ScalaClassLoader.scala:101)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.run(ObjectRunner.scala:22)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.run(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
        at scala.tools.nsc.CommonRunner$class.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:29)
        at scala.tools.nsc.ObjectRunner$.runAndCatch(ObjectRunner.scala:39)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.runTarget$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:65)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.run$1(MainGenericRunner.scala:87)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.process(MainGenericRunner.scala:98)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:103)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

It can run in the IDEA, but when I package it, it cannot run. Is there something missing in the pom.xml? the scala version is 2.11.12